# Error creating new transfer in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying transfer data from DCM to BigQuery but I keep getting this error:

> Error in creating a new transfer. Please ensure the OAuth popup was not blocked and you have the BigQuery Admin role.

I removed the pop-up blocker in Chrome and I have the BigQuery Admin role so not sure why I keep getting this error. Is someone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are still not allowing the Pop-Up to appear. Check if you have an extension or something blocking it.

Check this [[1]](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) to make sure you are allowing them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your parameters are set correctly - it gave me the above error message even when popups weren't blocked and I had the correct permissions - it turned out I was requesting the query to run every 1 minute and the minimum interval is 15mins.